# PowerBiClient change cursor to default

Tags: asynchronous, powerbi, mouse

I am creating a WinForm application which uses PowerBIClient package. In a UI event, the cursor is changed to WaitCursor by my code before calling a PowerBIClient async method. But the cursor is changed back to default by the async method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the WaitCursor set by Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor is reset back to default by async call. But the form's cursor property is not impacted by async call.